# JsonPath array length() returns number of keys instead of elements

Tags: java, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have the following array:

```
"books" : [ {
  "title" : "History",
  "id":1

}, {
  "title" : "The Robotics",
  "id":2

}, {
  "title" : "The World",
   "id":3
} ]
```

and my JsonPath notation is this: `$.books[?(@.title == 'History')].length()` . I'm expecting it to return 1 (because it matches a single book), but it returns 2, which is a number of keys in the first object(that got matched). How can I force/change it to return the number of elements, not keys in the object?

Im using [this](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library for java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the dot (`.`). You have only one but you need two. This works:

```
$..books[?(@.title == 'History')].length()
```

Comment: Thanks @Timon. The thing is that I don't write the java code, Im using library that does this for me. The strange thing is that when I write `$.books.length()` it returns 3 as expected , but  if I have filter and then length() , it counts keys in object

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working solution.

Comment: It still gives me 2, but I guess this is due to the library Im using. Thanks anyway

Comment: Btw, how can I check if array is empty, I tries empty(), but does not work

Comment: It seems my answer doesn't help. This code always returns length 1. I'll remove this answer in a few minutes.